# Prevent ComboBox from updating displayed text when datasource changes

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datasource, bindinglist

I have a ComboBox which is bound to a BindingList.
The background is that I want to have an option to choose from the dropdown-list (as a suggestion), but I don't want to change the displayed text if the ItemsSource changes (for example, when I'm adding an item to the BindingList).

Is there a way to prevent the ComboBox to update the displayed text when the items source is changed?

Some code:

```
this.comboBox1.DataSource = database.ListItems; // database.ListItems is of type BindingList<string>

public void update_ListItems(BindingList<string> ListItems)
{
    ListItems.Add("Item"); // Causes an update of the displayed text in the ComboBox 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to break the binding between ComboBox and data source you can convert the BindingList to List like this:

```
this.comboBox1.DataSource = database.ListItems.ToList();
```

This will prevent updating of ComboBox items when you change the BindingList